# Disable logging completly SP2013

Tags: 2013, logging

I have followed every guide there is, and also even tried to disable logging through this PowerShell command.

```
Set-SPUsageService -LoggingEnabled $false
Set-SPLogLevel -TraceSeverity None -EventSeverity None
```

But still my logs folder is spammed with log files.

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663480.aspx

How can this be? Do I have to restart some kind of service in order for it to work?

Comment: I am just curious why you want to disable the logging? Due to space or something else? Run get command and see what login level set.

Comment: `Get-SPLogLevel` Reveals that all entries has "None" "None". So it should be alright. I want to disable it because im beeing flooded with `Forced due to logging gap` messages, and CPU is running at 100%.

Comment: Did u use the enablefloodprotection... https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748656.aspx

Comment: Yes, I ran `Set-SPDiagnosticConfig -EventLogFloodProtectionEnabled` still no luck. Logs are flooded.

Comment: How many server in farm?did u recycle sp timer services....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried in my farm the below steps and its worked as expcted.

1. Set-SPLogLevel -TraceSeverity None
2. Set-SPLogLevel -EventSeverity None

Now all categories showing the none. and i checked the ULS logs, nothing after that.

Another way to stop it, their is one Timer services which is responsible for this called **sharepoint tracing services**, try to stop on all servers.

- To Stop net stop SPTrace
- To start net start SPTrace

Comment: I already did part 1 and 2.But stopping the service did the trick. i had to use `net stop SPTraceV4` and not `net stop SPTrace`. Thanks, and I will look into why the log was flooded later.